# Can't import from flask_mail

Tags: python, flask, pycharm, anaconda, flask-mail

I can't seem to be able to import flask-mail.

I installed it via pip and it was already there through anaconda. So i uninstalled it and reinstalled it but still no chance of importing it.

```
Requirement already satisfied: Flask-Mail in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/Flask_Mail-0.9.1-py3.9.egg (0.9.1)
Requirement already satisfied: Flask in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask-Mail) (1.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: blinker in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask-Mail) (1.7.0)
Requirement already satisfied: Werkzeug>=0.15 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Mail) (2.0.3)
Requirement already satisfied: Jinja2>=2.10.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Mail) (2.11.3)
Requirement already satisfied: itsdangerous>=0.24 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Mail) (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: click>=5.1 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Flask->Flask-Mail) (8.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: MarkupSafe>=0.23 in ./opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from Jinja2>=2.10.1->Flask->Flask-Mail) (2.0.1)
```

I believe it worked in the beginning but at some point it just didn't anymore.

```
import os
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_from_directory
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

mail = Mail(app)
```

What am I missing?
40V3

Comment: I think that you have installed `flask_mail` globally. Activate your anaconda virtual environment first by writing `conda activate` in the terminal. Then install the package. I am seeing that you are using PyCharm, install the package through PyCharm's terminal instead of the OS terminal. To ensure that you have activated the virtual environment, you will see the project name between parenthesis before the starting of the command line.

Comment: Oh wow.. Yup that was easy. Thank you very much! <3